# Exit from a loop that contains time delay immediately after a key is pressed

Tags: c, loops, timedelay

I would like to implement a function that will exit a countdown timer loop if a key is pressed or if the time runs out. I am using time delay to make the count down timer and after the time delay, the console will refresh. however, it doesn't exit from the loop when I press a key. can anyone help?

here is my code:

```
int b=0;

while(minutes_left>0)
{
    for(minutes_left=minutes_left;minutes_left>0 && b==0;minutes_left-=10)
    {
        system("cls");
        banner();
        printf("    TIME LEFT\n");
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("     %d:%d0\n",(minutes_left/60), (minutes_left%60)/10);
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("\nPress any key to enter you transaction code and finish parking\n");
        b=kbhit();
        Sleep(10000);
    }

}
```

Comment: try reducing the sleep time. From what I see here the code should exit the cycle when you press a key. What compiler are you using?

Comment: make inner loop for wait and check keyboard in one process

Comment: i want the values to change every 10 seconds. im using C-free for windows.

Comment: @Dims How do I do that? (sorry im a beginner)

Answer (score 6):

`kbhit()` doesn't wait for any input, it just returns if there is a key pressed at
 the very instant you make the test. So in this case you never hit the key exactly when you need to and you're dropping into the Sleep right away.

Normal usage is something like:

```
while (!kbhit())
```

So you can sit and wait for a key press. In your case since you want to sleep, you should probably do some sort of "count down" operation checking for a key press... I don't have a great example off the top of my head so let's just say:

```
int countdown;
for(minutes_left=minutes_left;minutes_left>0 && b==0;minutes_left-=10)
{
    countdown = 0;
    system("cls");
    ...
    while(countdown++ <= 1000){  // give a second to hit something
        if(b=kbhit())            // if the user presses a key
            break;               // leave the loop early
        Sleep(1);                // else, sleep for 1 ms and try again
    }
    if (b == 0)          // if nothing was pressed
        Sleep(9000);     // sleep for another 9s
```

---

**EDIT:**
I think your problem might be else where in the code... I dusted off the old windows computer and gave it a try:

```
int main()
{
    int i, b = 0, countdown;
    for(i = 0; i<10000 && b ==0; i++)
    {
         countdown = 0;
         system("cls");
         printf("menu stuff %d\n", i);
         while(countdown++ <= 1000) {
           if(b = kbhit())
              break;
           Sleep(1);
         }
         if(b == 0)
           Sleep(9000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program works for me to get the input and break out of the sleep mechanism.

Comment: it doesnt work, but thank you for trying to help. appreciate it

Comment: @IfanIrsyad - sorry about that... have you tried a subprogram with something like my first note `while(!kbhit()) {print something}` to make sure that it's working correctly at all?

Comment: @IfanIrsyad - Just thought I'd show you an example of this code working. You might want to check my above edit against your code, because this works to update the screen every 10s and gets the input from the user to break out.

Answer (score 2):

Do extra loop for waiting with smaller time granulation:

```
int b=0;
int count;

while(minutes_left>0)
{
    for(minutes_left=minutes_left;minutes_left>0 && b==0;minutes_left-=10)
    {
        system("cls");
        banner();
        printf("    TIME LEFT\n");
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("     %d:%d0\n",(minutes_left/60), (minutes_left%60)/10);
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("\nPress any key to enter you transaction code and finish parking\n");

        // replacing your's
        //b=kbhit();
        //Sleep(10000);

        // with inner loop
        for(count=0; count<100&& (b=kbhit())==0; count++) {
            Sleep(100);
        }

        // this loop will wait for 10000 milliseconds but in portions of 100
        // periodically it will check keyboard
        // user will be required to keep key pressed for at least 0.1 second
        // to be caught by the loop

    }

}
```

BTW, what for have you enclosed inner `for` in additional `while`?